# php imap_open Gmail sent folder returns empty array

Tags: php, laravel, email, imap

So my code looks like this:

```
$mailbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}Sent Mail', env('MAIL_USERNAME'), env('MAIL_PASSWORD'));
$mailsIds = imap_search($mailbox, 'ALL');
```

And I get `false`. I've tried changing "Sent Mail" to "[Google Mail]/Sent Mail", "Sent", "SENT MAIL" and "SENT", but I get `false` all the time, but there ARE emails in this folder. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well I called function that shows a list of all available folders and got several imap utf7 encoded variants, from which `[Gmail]/&BBIEQQRP- &BD8EPgRHBEIEMA-` was exactly what I needed.